# Transffering TYPO3 Site to a New Host Issue

Tags: typo3

I have a website built with TYPO3. ([www.fibo-nrw.de](http://www.fibo-nrw.de)) I moved this site to a different server with the same name (without changing the domain). I have transferred all files and databases in full. Currently I can access the backend, I can see all my files, but I cannot view the site. Where could I be doing wrong? My TYPO version is 6

Comment: As the frontend returns a 500 Internal Server Error you should have a look into the error log (presumably typo3temp/logs or something - don't know the exact place in v6). If everything works then, consider updating to a supported TYPO3 version, as v6 is not supported anymore and may have security issues.

Comment: There are logs in typo3temp folder but typo3.log file is empty. Nothing written. I also mark it as show all errors from php.ini, but it does not give any warning on the screen. It just gives 500 errors.

Comment: Check the server logs/php log in generall. Eventuall Remove your .htaccess if apache is used - and try the core shipped one/documented. Ensure server havd all needed modules installed etc. And that you are using a suitable php-version.